# How to save contents of CanvasControl as an image file

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win2d

I'm making a paint-like program using [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D). My `CanvasControl` contains some text, images and some lines which the user has drawn. I want to save the entire contents of this `CanvasControl` as a file on disk (in any standard image format). I want to do this as I want to display it (at a later time) inside a standard `Image` control.

How would I do this? I tried using `RenderTargetBitmap` to load the `CanvasControl` (code below) but for some reason it clips the image and only a small horizontal top-portion image is made.

---

```
async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        #region (c) rendering UIElement to bitmap code

        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await bitmap.RenderAsync(ccDraw); // ccDraw is CanvasControl

        // get the pixels
        IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

        // write the pixels to a InMemoryRandomAccessStream
        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixels);

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        stream.Seek(0);

        Image iNew = new Image();
        iNew.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        iNew.Source = bitmap;
        gOuter.Children.Add(iNew);
        ccDraw.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // hide CanvasControl so we can see added image 

     #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Can you show code, where you tried `RenderTargetBitmap`?

Comment: @RenDishen I added the code I'm using

Comment: Check my answer below. I think you were saying basically you want to save the canvas as an image correct?

Comment: @thewisegod Yes. I was trying out your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i did this for me. `imageSize` is size of your image, for example `var imageSize = new Size(500,500);`

```
var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

ccDraw.Measure(imageSize);
ccDraw.UpdateLayout();
ccDraw.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height));

var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(ccDraw, Convert.ToInt32(imageSize.Width), Convert.ToInt32(imageSize.Height));

var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Screen.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
      var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, fileStream);

      encoder.SetPixelData(
              BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
              BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
              (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
              (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
              displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
              displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
              pixelBuffer.ToArray());

      await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void SaveCanvasAsImage()
    {
        Rect yourRect = new Rect(ccDraw.RenderSize);
        RenderTargetBitmap rtBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)yourRect.Right,
        (int)yourRect.Bottom, 100d, 100d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
        rtBitmap.Render(ccDraw);

        BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtBitmap));

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        pngEncoder.Save(ms);
        ms.Close();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("yourPng.png", ms.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seem to fit into a Windows Store/WinRT app. Is this WPF code ? It says `RenderTargetBitmap` doesn't have a definition for `Render` method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly save the contents of a CanvasControl.

However, if you draw to an intermediate CanvasRenderTarget then you can save that using [SaveAsync](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Overload_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_SaveAsync.htm).

More information on drawing offscreen can be found at http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Offscreen.htm.

There's other benefits to drawing to a CanvasRenderTarget rather than drawing directly to the CanvasControl - the most obvious is that it allows you to do additive rendering, rather than having to redraw the entire display each time.

Comment: Thank you I'll be needing to draw offscreen also. But I was able to get an image file of it's contents (consisting of lines, didn't test images) using the code that RenDishen had mentioned.